# Does a steering wheel controller offer advantages over a standard controller that will help me improve in a racing game?

Tags: controllers

This applies to pretty much any racing game. What advantages, if any, does a steering wheel controller offer over a standard (analog) controller that will help me improve?

Or is the steering wheel just for fun?

---

Edit note: I changed the wording of this question to make it less subjective. The original intent is the same, though.

Comment: Now I feel schizophrenic because I upvoted both answers even though they say the exact opposite of one another...  :)

Comment: Just means they're both good answers. Also that the question's a little subjective.

Comment: *crosses fingers for eventually creating a mainstream tag*

Comment: @Galactic - I edited this to make it less subjective.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer to your question really depends on a number of factors:

- Do you approach it as a "game" or a "sim"?  I.e. what level of realism do you want?  For a realistic experience, you just can't beat a wheel and pedals.
- What kind of controller do you use?  A cheap plastic wheel with bungie cord springs isn't going to give you the same level of enjoyment and realism as a high-quality wheel.  However, you can pay a *lot* of money for dedicated controllers that will end up seeing relatively little use.
- Does the game support multiple analog inputs, and/or allow you to map the inputs according to your play style?  Regardless of controller, in many games it is important to be able to feather the throttle, etc.  I really hate the games that only give you a couple of preset controller mappings, since they almost never match what I want.

For myself, I have used the following:

- Joystick
- Home-built wheel/pedals (can't use it anymore because my computer no longer has a game port)
- Act Labs Force RS wheel/pedals/shifter (with "pro" pedals)
- Multiple gamepads and console controllers

Of these, I still use the Act Labs whenever I want to do "serious" racing but the gamepad is sufficient for arcade racers.  I've played all the way through NFS: Underground with the wheel and a gamepad, and wouldn't say it was significantly better one way or the other.

Background/disclaimer: for a number of years I was deeply involved in the racing simulation scene, including an extended stint as the webmaster of Sim Racing Connection where I also maintained the track/addon lists for GPL, DTR and SCGT.  I've played just about every racing sim/game ever made, all the way from Grand Prix Legends to Mario Kart.  :)

Answer (score 3):

From my point of view: Not at all. All steering wheels I tested didn't help me to drive better. It somehow feels very unnatural (nothing compared to sitting in a real car - maybe due to the lack of g forces/inertia).

Therefore I prefer game pads with analog sticks: The sticks give You enough precision to confidently maneuver Your car and - at the same time - allow for fast reactions due to the short moving radius.

Answer (score 3):

I have played Gran Tourismo 3 (yea, that long ago) with both a racing wheel and a regular PS2 controller. Over all I would say that it did not help my driving. The thing I like about a regular controller is that you can move the joystick way faster than you can a racing wheel. For some this is bad because their turns need to be precise. For others this is good because you can quickly correct a bad turn.

Basically, it's all a series of trade offs and it's not a one-size-fits-all type of thing.

Answer (score 2):

In general, yes it's better to have a steering wheel, but theoretically, any analog control stick can give you the same precision, but it would be a lot harder to use such a controller as effectively as a racing wheel, because it's easier to get the right amount of turn.

Answer (score 0):

The game should play equally well with either controller. Unless they distribute a wheel controller free with the game the manufacturers can't force people to buy the extra hardware.

There might be a different experience, but the game should be playable without a wheel.

Comment: That's just an opinion on how games should be made. Besides, "playable" isn't the point the point here, the question is about the differences between a wheel and a gamepad.